# How to mark column as non-updatable in room

Tags: android, android-room, readonly-attribute

How can I mark a field as non-updatable in room

In my products table, I have barcode and unit id, I don't want the barcode to get updated when I update unit id

fields look like this,

```
@SerializedName("barcode")
@Expose
private String barcode;

@SerializedName("unitid")
@Expose
private int unitId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set value in the unitid variable and don't set value in barcode variable in your entity.

Comment: I have more than a couple of thousands of products, then I have to loop through all the items and update individually. That is the only way I found for now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any thing like that in room ,

How ever You can use query to achieve it , use something like

```
 @Query("Update yourtablename set unitId=:unitId Where primaryKey=:primaryKey")
 fun updateBarCode(unitId:Int,primaryKey:Int)
```

you can also completely use ignore field using `@Ignore` annotation on field

Room will ignore that field or method.